# false site-web description when sharing the site web on social networks

Tags: wordpress, facebook, share

i have a WordPress site, i am using Yoast plugin to optimize it, Yoast give you the ability to customize the thumbnail and the description of any page when you share it in social networks,

the problem is that when i try to share my web site in Facebook or whatsapp, the Facebook take a false description, actually he take the button names!! (i have buttons with the title "visit our tours")

i tried to add to the header of the website open-graph meta , but with no result the Facebook still pick the wrong description..

what should i do ?

website url: http://www.himoroccotours.com/ you can log to the website and see the code source, you will notice that i have two descriptions the one i made, an other one i don't know how the website pull it !

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjsb0.png)

Comment: _“you will notice that i have two descriptions the one i made, an other one i don't know how the website pull it”_ – well then you have to find out ... it is _your_ site, we have no idea how you have configured it.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook updates their open graph cache periodically so sometimes you have to force it.  To do that, you can use their debugger tool which will update the cache when you run it.

Here's the link with your site in it.  Try sharing it now and see what the og data says.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.himoroccotours.com%2F

Note the "scrape again" button next to the "Time Scraped" field too.

Comment: i did it but doesn't work;
i get this errors: 

Extraneous Property
Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'DC.date.issued'.
Extraneous Property
Objects of this type do not allow properties named '”og:image”'.
Extraneous Property
Objects of this type do not allow properties named '”og:title”'.
.....

Comment: i noticed that i have two 'og data' one that i add by yoast seo, and an other that i don't know where it comes from ... i even tryied to use a pulgin vould "find and replace" so that i can replace the wrong og meta description with the one i want ...but non of that works

Comment: It's hard to tell where the 2nd set of OG data is coming from without getting into your WordPress install.  But presumably from another plugin similar to yoast?

Comment: if i give the link of the website would it help, by seeing the website source code , the website is : himoroccotours.com